# Related rates of change cone question

Tags: derivatives

Im unsure how to do this question after attempting it a few times. Please help!

A Container is in the form of a right circular cone of height 16 and base radius 4 is held vertex downward and filled with liquid. If the liquid leaks our from the vertex at a rate of 4 find the rate of change of the depth of the liquid in the cone when half of the liquid has leaked out.

Thank.

Comment: Where did your prior attempts break down?

Comment: I tried to do dh/dt because the question asks for the depth of the water which i assuming meaning heigh, but I dont know how to find dv/dh, in addition I feel like there must be some sort of trig involved but am not sure how to incorporate it.

Comment: How fast is the fluid leaving the container?  The rate of change in the level equals speed of the leak divided by the surface area at the water level.

Comment: Correct, you have $dV/dt$ (at one moment); you want to know $dh/dt$.  The missing piece is $dV/dh$.  Similar triangles might help with finding an equation relating $V$ and $h$.

Comment: I did everything you all told me to do and figured it out, the only problem is i dont know what to sub in for h at the end. I tried 8, but it didnt give me -0.126 which is the answer, any help there?

Answer (score 1):

The change in height is the volume of the leak divided by the surface area at the water level.

The volume of water in the cone is $\alpha r^3$

When it is full it is  $64\alpha$

and when it is half full, it is $32\alpha.$

And the radius of the surface of the water is $32^{\frac 13}$

The surface area is $\pi 32^\frac 23$

$\frac {4}{\pi 32^\frac 23} = \frac 1{\pi\sqrt[3]{16}}$

But you wanted to use calculus

$V = \frac 13 \pi r^2 h\\
h = 4r$

$V = \frac 13 \pi (4r^3) =  \frac 13 \pi \frac {h^3}{16}\\
\frac {dv}{dt}=4=\pi {h^2}{16} \frac {dh}{dt}$

We need to find $h$ when the tank is half full.

When the tank is full, $h = 16$

$V = \frac 13 \pi (4r^3) =  \frac 13 \pi 256$

and when it is half full

$V = \frac 13 \pi (4r^3) =  \frac 13 \pi 128$

$h = \frac {16}{2^\frac 13} = 2^{11}{3}$

$2^2=\pi \frac {2^{\frac {22}{3}}}{2^4} \frac {dh}{dt}\\
\frac {dh}{dt} = \frac {2^6}{\pi2^\frac {22}{3}} = \frac 1{\pi 2^{\frac 43}}$